# Vue not updating

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue js - the following is not updating:

```
<div id="error" class="col s12 red center">
  <span v-if="seen">
    Error fetching readings: {{ msg }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
var error = new Vue({
  el: '#error',
  data: {
    msg: '',
    seen: false
  },
  methods: {
    show: function(message) {
      this.msg = message;
      this.seen = true;
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.seen = false;
    }      
  }
});
```

Post fetch:

```
fetch( ... )
.then(...)
.catch(err => {
    error.show( err );
    loader.hide();
});
```

error.show() displays the previously hidden div, but displays:

```
Error fetching readings: {}
```

Why?

Comment: And what is actually the error? Did you log it or inspected it with the developers tools?

Comment: I'm forcing the error in order to test this bit of code; the error text is "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Comment: If I call error.show( 'Error!' ) instead of error.show(err), the rendering works as expected: "Error fetching readings: Error!"

Answer (score 0):

i created a CodeSandbox sample based upon your code, you need to have computed property to have the Vue reactivity

Sample can be found, check code in HelloWorld.vue in components folder
https://codesandbox.io/s/x2klzr59wo

```
<template>
  <div id="error" class="col s12 red center">
    {{ seen }}
    <hr />
    <span v-if="computedSeen"> Error fetching readings: {{ msg }} </span>
    <hr />
    <button @click="show('effe');">SHOW</button> &nbsp;
    <button @click="hide();">HIDE</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      seen: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    show: function(message) {
      this.msg = message;
      this.seen = true;
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.seen = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedSeen: function() {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.seen;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, problem was `err` from the `fetch` is an object, and I should have used `err.message`.

In my code I had a `console.log('Error: %s', err)` which appears to format the `err` object into text. Which is what threw me :(

Sorry.